# attach event handler to Column Chart in google charts

Tags: charts, google-visualization

How to add Event Listeners to google charts(Column Chart) column name(label).
For example, the lables such as 2004,2005,2006, 2007 should throw events.

When the user clicks on column name(label), event(select) should be triggered.

There is a provision to add event listener to the visualisation data but not to the column label.

Fire an event with the name 'select' when the user selects some data **within** the visualization. The event does not send any arguments to the listening functions.
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/events#The_Select_Event

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a "click" event handler:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'click', function(e) {
    var match = e.targetID.match(/hAxis#\d#label#(\d)/);
    if (match != null && match.length) {
        var rowIndex = parseInt(match[1]);
        // get the value from column 0 in the clicked row
        var label = data.getValue(rowIndex, 0);
        alert('You clicked on ' + label);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is the following: each column label is created as svg `text` element like:

```
<g>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="233.75" y="425.9" font-family="Arial" font-size="14" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">2004</text>
</g>
```

so you can get those elements and attach event listeners using:

```
    var colLabels = document.querySelectorAll('text[text-anchor="middle"]');

    for (var i = 0; i < colLabels.length; ++i) {
        console.log(colLabels[i]);
        colLabels[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            console.log(this.innerHTML);

            console.log('event');
            console.log(e);
        }, false); 
    }
```

There is a problem with this approach: you will attach event listener also to hAxis title `Year` so you will have to filter it out.